# How to output only specific digits from a list using sed?

Tags: sed

How do I write a sed invocation to output only lines containing only numbers consisting of a repeated single digit (and containing at least two digits).

Example:

```
seq 1000 | sed ...
```

For which the output should be:

```
11
22
33
44
55
66
77
88
99
111
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if sed is your favorite, here you go:

```
kent$  seq 1000|sed -nr '/^([0-9])\1+$/p'
11
22
33
44
55
66
77
88
99
111
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
```

Answer (score 2):

If `grep` is fine with you, you can try:

```
seq 1000 | egrep '^([0-9])\1+$'
```